# Why the main routine in Kotlin is accepted as a single-expression?

Tags: function, methods, kotlin

The entry point of the c-like languages is almost identical, so Kotlin's `fun main() {}`

This is quite understandable for me, however; when using this routine as a single-expression function and (assign?) it any output method it will be compiled and print the parameter's value of the print method not its return type (which is `Unit`).  I guess this snippet will make it clear..

```
fun main() = print("Do I return something?")
```

This will be compiled as a basic hello world program!

- Why is this acceptably compiled? does the main method returns something else than the 0?
- Is the equal operator acts as assignment operator? and if so; what does the `print()` method returns? is it something other than `Unit`?
- If so, why it returns `Unit` when assign it to a variable?

```
fun main() {
    val x= println()
    print(x)
}
```

Then also, why it doesn't return `Unit` in this case:

```
fun main() = foo()
fun foo(): Unit {}
```

Comment: the return type of `main` is `Unit`. `println`'s return type is also `Unit`. that's why it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not understanding everything you ask. `=` here is not an assignment operator. It's just a shorter way of writing the method:

```
 fun main() = print("Do I return something?")
```

is equivalent to

```
fun main(): Unit {
    return print("Do I return something?")
}
```

And since `print()`'s return type is `Unit`, it's equivalent to

```
fun main() {
    print("Do I return something?")
}
```

See [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#single-expression-functions) for details.

In the following snippet, however, `=` **is** the assignment operator:

```
fun main() {
    val x = println()
    print(x)
}
```

So this code calls `println()`, and assigns what it returns (`Unit`) to the variable `x`. Printing `x` thus produces the output `kotlin.Unit`.

Comment: How could you not understand anything and yet you answered me! anyway It is clear now, and excuse my limited English.

Comment: I did understand something. But not *every* thing.

Answer (score 2):

I hope that helps:

- The entry point to a Kotlin program is `fun main(): Unit` or `fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit`, which are functions that return `Unit`
- `Unit` is something that is returned by default from Kotlin functions when there is nothing interesting to return
- `println()` returns `Unit`
- A `Unit` return type is often omitted in the code, but it is implied
- `fun foo(): T = boo()` is a short syntax for `fun foo(): T { return boo() }`
- Since `fun main(): Unit` and `fun println(...): Unit` have the same return type `Unit`, it is valid to write `fun main() = println()`

Comment: Got it from the last sentence